# How do I create navbar links with background images?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new at all of this.  I am a library science student, and I am trying to create a simple navigation structure that features a background image that sits above hover and active links in the nav.  I have looked at this for a pretty long time, and (while the code as a whole may not be perfect--I'm sorry! I'm learning!) this is the part that I'm really struggling with.

Here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="ex4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="instruction.html">Instruction</a></li>
        <li><a href="innovation.html">Innovation</a></li>
         <li><a href="community.html">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
 @charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

#nav {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 30px 20px 0 20px;
    background-color: lavender;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    top: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2B2434;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    align-content: center;
}

#nav ul li a {
    padding: 30px 20px 15px 20px;
}

#nav ul a:link, #nav ul a:visited {
    color: #443743;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul a:hover, #nav ul a:active {
    color: #443743;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(/document.png);   
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize I didn't make that clear.  The background images aren't appearing in the navigation bar.

Comment: Please check your image path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your image image path:

```
background-image: url("/document.png");
```